# How to validate array size on update with mongoose

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I have this model on mongoose

```
const WorkOrderSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Enter a title for the order'
    }, 
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: 'Enter a description for the order'
    },
    deadline: {
        type: Date,
        required: 'Enter a deadline for the order'
    },
    workers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Worker" }]
});

WorkOrderSchema.path('workers').validate(function(workers) {
    if(workers.length > 5){return false}
    return true;
}, 'Too many workers');

module.exports = mongoose.model('Orders', WorkOrderSchema);
```

and this code that assigns workers to the order.

```
exports.assign_a_worker = function(req, res) {
    Order.update({"_id": req.params.orderId}, 
        {"$addToSet": {"workers": req.params.workerId}},
        {runValidators: true},
        function (err, order) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(order);
        }
    );      
};
```

However it doesn't validate the number of workers in the array and allows me to add unlimited objects to the workers array in the model. Not really sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Refer to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html : "$push, $addToSet, $pull, and $pullAll validation does not run any validation on the array itself, only individual elements of the array."

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc do you know how to validate on the array then?

Comment: I haven't do anything like this before, but you can try to find document first then modify and call `.save()`